# How to pass in a dict to a multiprocessing pool worker

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to have a multithreaded python script where a function has a dict as input and returns output. As such, I figured the best way to do this would be with `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`, because this is the only library I found where you can run a function on another thread and get a return value from it. However, when I pass in a dict as an argument, it seems to pass in the keys as a series of arguments rather than passing in the dict like I want.

Here's a snippet showing what I'm trying to do:

```
  1 from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
  2 
  3 def fun(i, u = None): #this function needs i to be a dict, or else it fails!
  4     print(i)
  5     assert(type(i) == dict)
  6     return i[0]
  7 
  8 pool = ThreadPool()
  9 dictionary = {'bread':'butter', 'pb':'j'}
 10 assert(type(dictionary) == dict) #dictionary is clearly a dict
 11 async_workers = [pool.apply_async(fun, args=(dictionary)) for i in range(10)] #we want it to pass in dictionary as an argument
 12 pool.close()
 13 pool.join()
 14 input() #funny thing; none of the workers start no matter how long I wait here, even though the documentation says it should be
 15 for i in async_workers:
 16     print(i.get()) #crashes here
```

So my understanding from reading the documentation is that line 11 should be spawning workers that start running fun() right away, and passing in dictionary as an argument because it's an object in the args tuple. Instead what happens is that none of the workers get started until I try to get() them (by hitting enter and getting out of the input call), then they print 'bread' and crash:

```
bread
bread
bread
bread
bread
bread
bread
bread
bread
bread

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chloe/Programming/Pytris-AI/min_error.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(i.get()) #crashes here
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/chloe/Programming/Pytris-AI/min_error.py", line 5, in fun
    assert(type(i) == dict)
AssertionError
```

This indicates that it's internally breaking up the dict and passing in all the keys as individual arguments.

So am I reading the documentation wrong? Is there a better library to use for this purpose? I looked at `threading` but it doesn't let me get return values from the threads as far as I could tell.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `(dictionary)` does not create a tuple you need to add a comma: `(dictionary,)`

Comment: @KlausD. Yup, that was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to add a comma. Ty!

```
  1 from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
  2 
  3 def fun(i, u = None): #this function needs i to be a dict, or else it fails!
  4     print(i)
  5     assert(type(i) == dict)
  6     return i[0]
  7 
  8 pool = ThreadPool()
  9 dictionary = {'bread':'butter', 'pb':'j'} #Needed a comma here
 10 assert(type(dictionary) == dict)         #            v
 11 async_workers = [pool.apply_async(fun, args=(dictionary,)) for i in range(10)] #we want it to pass in dictionary as an argument
 12 pool.close()
 13 pool.join()
 14 input() #funny thing; none of the workers start no matter how long I wait here, even though the documentation says it should be
 15 for i in async_workers:
 16     print(i.get()) #crashes here
```